# Can I cut the wood between struts in my attic?

Tags: wood, roof, attic

My attic has these 1x4 slats nailed between struts in my attic. They don't seem to be very important, as they're clearly not load bearing. They also seem to be put up pretty sloppily. The problem is, I'm a big guy, and navigating around these this is pretty painful. Can I safely cut these without compromising the roof?

[image: My attic]

Comment: Should be fine. They help keep the 24" OC during construction.

Comment: They were probably installed to maintain spacing. 1x wood is not structural.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am just going to confirm what has already been stated in the comments but add a little more to it. Yes the slats are to help keep spacing and are not structural.....anymore.

During the construction of the roof system these are also used to keep the trusses from falling over with the help of a number of diagonal braces before the plywood roof sheathing is put down. I have in the past, seen in the install guide for roof trusses how to place these braces during assembly, including the diagonals. There has never been a reference about removing them later, but I see no reason to leave them.

As a mention, instead of cutting them out, bring a hammer with you or pry bar and remove the whole thing. Cutting them out brings to mind rough ends, possibly splinters a plenty, and if you are a big guy as I am, while moving between the trusses, the less things to rub against or snag onto the better.

Comment: Thank you! You mentioned diagonals.. There's a diagonal 2x4 right in front of my attic entrance that's problematic as well.. It's attached with nails, not that fancy pokey metal plate stuff.. Is this safe to remove as well? ([Photo](http://i.imgur.com/LpdAcQS.jpg))

Comment: That one is good to go too. It held the gable end until the roof plywood went down. When the trusses were installed, that was the first brace to go on and the most important one. Be careful how you pull it loose at the bottom, it may wrench around the bottom cord which serves as the support for the ceiling drywall and nail pops may occur.

Comment: +1 - Great idea to use a pry bar to remove the whole thing. Leaves you with a few good sized pieces of wood that can be saved and reused for another project, rather than being left with many nearly useless pieces.

Answer (score 1):

looks like a CLB (continuous lateral braces) and probably should NOT have been cut down!!

https://www.finehomebuilding.com/2007/11/06/why-brace-some-truss-webs-but-not-all